# Animation not animating in Swift 3 Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, animation, gif

When I run my application with the following code it only displays the first frame and doesn't loop through the other images.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var signUpMode = true
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()


    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signIn: UIImageView!

    //Animated sign in
    var counter = 0

    var animationStart = false

    var timer = Timer()

    func animateSignIn() {

        signIn.image = UIImage(named: "frame_\(counter)_delay-0.04s.gif")

        counter += 1

        if counter == 128 {

            counter = 0

        }
    }

    func animation (){

        if animationStart == true {

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.04, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.animateSignIn), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
```

Then I set `animationStart` to `true`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //remove root view controller navigation bar
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    animationStart = true
}
```

Comment: This might be an incredibly stupid question on my part, but where are you calling the `animation()` function?

Comment: I think thats the issue, how should I go about doing that? I'm kinda new to this

Comment: I would personally call it in `viewDidAppear`, but @christian's answer will probably also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you call the function `animation()`?

I think `viewDidLoad` should look like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //remove root view controller navigation bar
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    animationStart = true
    animation() //call animation
}
```

Comment: It's something very simple but can you accept as answer if it worked?

Comment: @HBrown whenever an answer contains a solution on SO, you should totally accept it